# How do you know what dwellers to send to what quests?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I often do not know whether I will be over(or under)shooting a quest by sending too much firepower or too little of it. There are icons of required level and cross hairs with numbers (still don't know what it means) but they offer little insight as to how much dwellers and weapons I should dedicate for an expedition.

Is there a way to assess the challenge a quest may pose?

Answer (score 4):

The cross-hairs with numbers means that the dweller must equip a weapon capable of doing that damage. For example, if the cross-hair number is 14, the dweller may equip a improved sniper rifle 11-14, but not a plama gun 12-13.

And of course, the challenge difficulty is basically told by the required level. If you have few dwellers available for quests, ensure that those with the lowest levels go to the mission with the lowest level requirements. Anyway, since you are limited to three simultaneous quests at most, soon you will have more than enough available dwellers at level 50 for the quests (For quests at level 50, it is better to send dwellers at level 50 and with a high SPECIAL).